# AttributeError in tvtk about SetViewPlaneNormal

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

**NOTE**: A temporary solution has been found : open `camera.py`, use `pass` and comment the content in function `_view_plane_normal_changed` then recompile it.

I'm using `python(x,y)2.7.5.1` . When I use some packages using tvtk like mayavi,it raise a `AttributeError:SetViewPlaneNormal.`
I have known it is because vtk has deprecated this method.
Does anyone know how to solve it?
The version of `vtk` is `5.10.1-3.`
The full trackback contains some blocks like this:

```
ERROR:traits:Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object:     vtkOpenGLCamera (06F89078)
    Debug: Off
    ...#There are too many lines here


Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_notifiers.py", line 381, in call_3
        self.handler( object, old, new )
    File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\camera.py", line 82, in _view_plane_normal_changed
        self._do_change(self._vtk_obj.SetViewPlaneNormal,
AttributeError: SetViewPlaneNormal
Exception occurred in traits notification handler.
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of your problem-related code?

Comment: The codes such as : from mayavi.mlab import test_surf;test_surf()

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error.  `test_surf()` works as intended on my setup. How do you expect anyone to debug your problem if you don't provide a full stack trace, let alone the pertinent information about your system such as backend, operating system, and python distribution?

Comment: I'm sorry. Anyway, thank you again. I'm new to both stackoverflow and vtk, so I'm not familiar with them. The whole trackback is too long, even IPython cannot hold them all(only about 500 lines).

Comment: I have solved it. Open "camera.py", pass the content in function _view_plane_normal_changed then recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the exact same issue. Any mayavi code leads to the `AttributeError:SetViewPlaneNormal` error.

My platform is Win 7 Pro x64, with Python 2.7.5, VTK 5.10.1, Mayavi 4.3.0.

Note that even official python examples leads to the error but despite the errors that are continously printing in the console, the graphics are correctly displayed.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
, trait: view_plane_normal, old value: [ 0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027], new value: [     0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_notifiers.py", line 381, in call_3
    self.handler( object, old, new )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\camera.py", line 82, in     _view_plane_normal_changed
    self._do_change(self._vtk_obj.SetViewPlaneNormal,
AttributeError: SetViewPlaneNormal
Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object: vtkOpenGLCamera (092BF010)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 890617
  Reference Count: 2
  Registered Events: 
    Registered Observers:
      vtkObserver (0A1AA3C8)
        Event: 33
        EventName: ModifiedEvent
        Command: 0A867210
        Priority: 0
        Tag: 1
  ClippingRange: (1.56289, 5.47286)
  DirectionOfProjection: (-0.57735, -0.57735, -0.57735)
  Distance: 3.29037
  EyeAngle: 2
  FocalDisk: 1
  FocalPoint: (1, 1, 1)
  ViewShear: (0, 0, 1)
  ParallelProjection: Off
  ParallelScale: 0.851612
  Position: (2.8997, 2.8997, 2.8997)
  Stereo: Off
  Left Eye: 1
  Thickness: 3.90998
  ViewAngle: 30
  UseHorizontalViewAngle: 0
  UserTransform: (none)
(none)
  ViewPlaneNormal: (0.57735, 0.57735, 0.57735)
  ViewUp: (0, 0, 1)
  WindowCenter: (0, 0)
  UseOffAxisProjection: (0)
  ScreenBottomLeft: (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
  ScreenBottomRight: (0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
  ScreenTopRight: (0.5, 0.5, -0.5)
  EyeSeparation: (0.06)
  WorldToScreenMatrix: (03996300
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 881548
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Elements:
        1 0 0 0 
        0 1 0 0 
        0 0 1 0 
        0 0 0 1 
  )
  EyeTransformMatrix: (039954F0
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 881550
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Elements:
        1 0 0 0 
        0 1 0 0 
        0 0 1 0 
        0 0 0 1 
  )
  ModelTransformMatrix: (039955E0
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 881552
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Elements:
        1 0 0 0 
        0 1 0 0 
        0 0 1 0 
        0 0 0 1 
  )

, trait: view_plane_normal, old value: [ 0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027], new value: [     0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_notifiers.py", line 381, in call_3
    self.handler( object, old, new )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\camera.py", line 82, in     _view_plane_normal_changed
    self._do_change(self._vtk_obj.SetViewPlaneNormal,
AttributeError: SetViewPlaneNormal
```

The above stack trace is printed several times per rendering. And keep happening if we move the camera leading to huge drop off of the FPS.

An example of the most trivial code leading to this error:

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.points3d([1], [1], [1])
```

Comment: Note that several people encounter this issue though none found a solution.

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.enthought.devel/32214

Comment: I found a way to get rid of the error but it is rather DIRTY:

in `PythonDIR\Lib\site-packages\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\camera.py
` edit function `_view_plane_normal_changed` (line 81), comment the line inside `self._do_change(self._vtk_obj.SetViewPlaneNormal, self.view_plane_normal)` and add `return`. This solution is really temporary and I'm still looking for clean solution !

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem using python(x,y)(2.7.5.2), but under Anaconda(1.8.0) distribution, the code works ok.

```
# code comes from mayavi docs shipped with python(x,y) 2.7.5.2
# Create the data.
from numpy import pi, sin, cos, mgrid
dphi, dtheta = pi/250.0, pi/250.0
[phi,theta] = mgrid[0:pi+dphi*1.5:dphi,0:2*pi+dtheta*1.5:dtheta]
m0 = 4; m1 = 3; m2 = 2; m3 = 3; m4 = 6; m5 = 2; m6 = 6; m7 = 4;
r = sin(m0*phi)**m1 + cos(m2*phi)**m3 + sin(m4*theta)**m5 + cos(m6*theta)**m7
x = r*sin(phi)*cos(theta)
y = r*cos(phi)
z = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta)

# View it.
from mayavi import mlab
s = mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
mlab.show()
```